# How to get user details in Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am building a Teams Bot which needs to send out Adaptive Cards to users.

When the bot is installed, i am sending a Welcome message to the user. From the welcome message, i am able to get the user's Teams ID using activity.from.id.

`From ID::29:1O_abckkskldjflkjfslxxxxxxxx`

With this id, i tried to get the User Details using 
`const member=TeamsInfo.getMember(context, context.activity.from.id);`

However I am still unable to get the user details.

How to get the email id of the user so that in future i can send notifications to the user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, you pass the "id" to getMember only for the dotnet libraries. For Node, it looks like it wants the email/UPN - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=typescript#get-single-member-details), whereas you're sending activity.from.id. Perhaps try call [getPagedMembers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=typescript#fetching-the-roster-or-user-profile) instead - if there's only one user (i.e. it's a 1-1 chat), it's effectively the same as getMember.

Working Snippet::

```
  this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
            for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; ++cnt) {
                if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                    var continuationToken;
                    var members = [];
                    do {
                        var pagedMembers = await TeamsInfo.getPagedMembers(context, 100, continuationToken);
                        continuationToken = pagedMembers.continuationToken;
                        members.push(...pagedMembers.members);
                    } while (continuationToken !== undefined);
                    members.forEach(member => {
                        const userEmail=member.userPrincipalName;
                    });
                    const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(welcomeCard);
                    const message = {
                        attachments: [card],
                        summary: 'Welcome'
                    };
                    await context.sendActivity(message);
                }
            }
            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
```

Comment: Great ! That's one of the way

Comment: I keep getting the error in the Emulatorv-  /v3/conversations/43652220-a984-11ea-a2a8-85520dca06e7%7Clivechat/pagedmembers does not exist. This might work only when running in the Teams chat, but it gives error from Teams as well

Comment: It's very possible that the emulator doesn't support this - to be honest, it's so easy to test in Teams directly, using ngrok, and there's such a variance in what the two technologies support, that I'd suggest using Teams as much as possible. So with that in mind, what error, if any, do you get from within Teams?

Comment: @AhmedVali Were you able to solve this problem? If yes, can you share how?

Comment: @AliNauman , using member.userPrincipalName you can get the user details. I have added the working snippet in the Answer.